# Can't access array or object value inside a loop that I have inside conditional statement/ Loop doesn't initiate

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What I mean by "can't access" is that the loop doesn't initiate. Sorry for the confusion.

I asked this question before, but I'm trying again with more detail and the complete-ish code.

Basically, I'm filtering output based on a user's input. However, I'm confused as to why I have no access to the `obj["Entry Fee"]` value and the `toFilterParams.entry` array inside the for loop that I have marked in the code above. I have access to it just before that loop starts, but nothing ever triggers inside the loop (yes, the array is visible before the for loop I marked and all the criteria is filled before the code starts).

I tried setting the object's value in a variable just before the loop starts, but obviously that didn't do anything.

For reference, `toFilterParams` is set up like `{games: [], entry: [], dates: []};`

Here is the code with the labeling of where I can access the array and the object value and where I cant:

```
db = _.without(_.map(dbTransition, function(obj){

    if("Starting_Date" in obj){

        if(toFilterParams.games.length > 0){

            // repeat of code I have below

        } else if(toFilterParams.games.length === 0){

            // Have access to obj["Entry Fee"] and toFilterParams.entry array**
            if(toFilterParams.entry.length > 0){

                // Have access to obj["Entry Fee"] and toFilterParams.entry array**

                for(var x = 0, xx = toFilterParams.entry; x < xx; x++){

                    // Have no access to obj["Entry Fee"] and toFilterParams.entry array aka the loop here doesn't initiate.**

                    if(Number(toFilterParams.entry[x]) !== Number(obj["Entry Fee"])){

                        if(toFilterParams.dates.length > 0){

                            var startDate = Date.parse(toFilterParams.dates[0]);
                            var endDate = Date.parse(toFilterParams.dates[1]);
                            var FinalDate = Date.parse(obj["Starting_Date"]);

                            if(FinalDate >= startDate && FinalDate <= endDate){
                                return obj;
                            }

                        } else{
                            return obj;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if(toFilterParams.entry.length === 0){

                if(toFilterParams.dates.length > 0){

                    var startDate = Date.parse(toFilterParams.dates[0]);
                    var endDate = Date.parse(toFilterParams.dates[1]);
                    var FinalDate = Date.parse(obj["Starting_Date"]);

                    if(FinalDate >= startDate && FinalDate <= endDate){
                        return obj;
                    }
                } else{
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}), undefined);
```

So basically, I have no idea what is going on and would like any help to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe what you have done for debugging?  Can you use the Chrome debugger / Firebug to look at this?

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes values of all the relevant variables?

Comment: Please define "access", an error occurs? How have you determined, that you don't have "access".

Comment: Not having access = the loop doesn't initiate = console.log doesn't fire inside the loop. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: @Julie I'm doing this on the Meteor framework, so all spelling issues and errors in the code are presented to me via terminal, so I always see it before the code can save and render.

Comment: When I console log `toFilterParams.entry` before the loop, the array is there and all the values are where they are supposed to be. What could be causing the falsy values to be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is never executed. This happens, because `toFilterParams.entry` is an array. In the condition of `for` loop you're checking against array. To fix this, you need to set the length of the array to `xx` not the array itself:

```
for(var x = 0, xx = toFilterParams.entry.length; x < xx; x++){...
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that fact. Thanks.